# Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session when UpgradeData

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, setup-upgrade, upgradeschema, area

I'm using magento verison 2.2.5 and i try to use Setup/UpgradeData.php to run a model function to insert data into database from an external API. but when i run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` i always got this error:

> Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.

i already set the area code before i run my model function like this:

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    public function __construct(
      \Vendor\Module\Model\Test $test,
      \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ){
      $this->test = $test;
      $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $test = $this->test;
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.3", "<")) { 
          $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
          $test->syncBankData();
          $test->syncCUstomerBankData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any extension in your project?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra yes i run this from my custom extension

Comment: please  check my answer, it should work

Answer (score 1):

It's issued found when we are using third party extension:
Change your counsturct code any try if it can help you:

```
public function __construct(
  \Vendor\Module\Model\Test $test,
  \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
){
  $this->test = $test;
  $this->state = $state;
  $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
}
```

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change area to setup instead of adminhtml, replace

```
$this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
```

with

```
  $this->state->setAreaCode('setup');
```

Reference -https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b366da/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php#L902-L902

Answer (score 0):

You have to use objectManager to initiate classes in your command classes as shown below -:

```
/**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    protected $_state;

    /**
     * Construct function for class UpdateSummary
     *
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Function to configure the command in magento 2
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('custom:function');
        $this->setDescription('Custom Function Description');
        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param InputInterface  $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->_state = $this->objectManager->get(State::class);
        $this->_helper = $this->objectManager->get(Helper::class);

        $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
        if ($this->_helper->isEnabled()) {
            .....
        } else {
            $output->writeln(__("Module is Disabled. Please enable the module to run this command"));
        }
    }
```